# Toggle show/hide with checkbox

Tags: jquery

**what im attempting:**

1. On page load hide all elements
2. on change of checkbox toggle show/hide of element

css:

```
.hide{
     display: none;
}
```

markup:

```
<form id="checkThis">
    <input type="checkbox" data-target="hide1" class="ck">check1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" data-target="hide2"class="ck">check2</input>
</form>

<div id="theHidden">
  <div id="hide1" class='hide'>Im Hidden On Page Load</div>
  <div id="hide2" class='hide'>Im Hidden On Page Load Too</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle for edited question: http://jsfiddle.net/1tx18jcy/

Comment: I didn't vote  it down, but I'm assuming its because similar questions have been asked many times. Also, an unrelated 'fyi': when you have 2 arguments for `prop()` it actually sets that property rather than gets it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" data-target='transom3' .../>    
<input type="checkbox" data-target='lsl3' .../>    
<input type="checkbox" data-target='door3' .../>
// ...
```

```
$(".partCheck").change(function(){
   $('#' + this.dataset.target).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: @mcG73 You are welcome, note that older browsers do no support `dataset` property, if you want to support older browsers, you can use jQuery `data()` method, `$(this).data('target')`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for...

http://jsfiddle.net/MYhTu/

```
$(".partCheck").click(function(){
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $("#"+$(this).val()).show();
  } else {
      $("#"+$(this).val()).hide();
  }
});
```

in the jsfiddle, you'll notice i updated the values to be equal to the id's of the parts they are associated with (i was guessing, but you can put in your own)

Answer (score -1):

Replace Javascript with this line:

```
$(".partCheck").attr("onclick", "if($(this).prop('checked') $('#'+$(this).val()).show(); else $('#'+$(this).val()).hide();");
```

And set the values of checkboxes to equal the dev IDs.